# How to encrypt the text field in browser without using Applets?

Tags: java, security, browser, applet, password-encryption

As browsers are ending the support for the plugin such as Applets, what are the alternatives for encrypting the text fields such as passwords in browser? Currently we are using applets to encrypt the password in text fields before sending to server.

Comment: Your best bet is to just make sure they're being submitted over HTTPS/SSL.

Comment: All our connections are using HTTPS/SSL, still we do encrypt the passwords entered in text fields before sending to the server. In server we decrypt this password. It is common in banking/finance industries.

Comment: Only very regionally, apparently. I've never heard of it in the US, Canada, or Europe. There's no advantage over existing HTTPS.

Comment: Never heard of it in Australia either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your new implementation will be, JavaScript has the ability to encrypt text strings. Here are a few libraries:

(We still use this)
https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

This is a popular one by Stanford
https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.